# в foreach для 1 цикла одно, для остального другое

Tags: php, foreach

есть цикл вида

```
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $number = 'first';           
}
```

и задача для 1 цикла задать 1 переменную, для остальных другую.
Как это сделать?

Comment: НИ-ЧЕ-ГО НЕ ПО-НЯТ-НО!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
$i++;
if ($i==1) {$number = 'first';} else {$number = 'second';}
}
```